# How to declare a function with the most generic signature in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

Here's my problem. I have a generic abstract class that looks like this:

```
export abstract class IGenericRepository<T> {
  abstract getOne(): Promise<T>; // this is incorrect, no args;
}
```

And I have another abstraction that extends the one above:

```
export class MongoGenericRepository<T> extends IGenericRepository<T> {
  override getOne(
    filter?: FilterQuery<T>,
    projection?: any | null,
    options?: QueryOptions | null,
    callback?: Callback<HydratedDocument<T> | null>,
  ): Promise<T> {
     // mongo method implementation
  }
}
```

The parameters in this mongo repository are well known, but the top level abstraction, that's the `IGenericRepository` is more abstract, let's put it this way. So the signature of the `getOne` method should be the most generic. How would you declare that method in `IGenericRepository`?

Comment: Probably getOne(...args: unknown[]). A more flexible way is to accept one options arg and destructure it, this way you aren't limited with the order of args.

Comment: Really unclear what you are going for here .. `export abstract class IGenericRepository<T, TArgs extends any[]> {
  abstract getOne(...args: TArgs[]): Promise<T>; 
}` or `getOne(...args: any[]): Promise<T>; ` or `getOne(...args: never[]): Promise<T>; ` or or `getOne(...args: unknown[]): Promise<T>; ` could all be valid options .. all with tradeoffs